# Python BeautifulSoup error element invisible when trying to find href?

Tags: python

I am trying to find a URL containing '.ics' in an href. I tested this code the other day and it was working perfectly, but now when I try to search 'for link in links', 'print link' results in:   ``

```
<a class="element-invisible element-focusable" href="#main-content" 
tabindex="1">Skip to main content</a>
<a class="element-invisible element-focusable" href="#main-content">Skip to 
main content</a>
```

Becuase of this, the 'if link.get('href')' code is never satisfied and the URL is not returned. What is causing this, and is there another way to return the URL containing '.ics'?

```
page = requests.get('https://registrar.fas.harvard.edu/calendar').content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

links = soup.find_all('a')
#print links    
for link in links:
    print link    

    if link.get('href') != None and '.ics' in link.get('href'):
        endout = link.get('href')

        if endout[:6] == 'webcal':
            endout ='https' + endout[6:]
        print
        print 'URL: ' + endout
        print
        return endout
    break
```

Comment: Why do you have a `return` outside a function?

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar How is it outside?

Comment: Well, in the code shown, there is no function, besides that, why do you call `break` in your `for` loop? This `break` is preventing the loop to run more than once and therefore to print more links.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar oh sorry, I forgot to include the def function part. Also, the break is intentional so that if any link with '.ics' is found, no need to check others as I just want the first one.

Comment: OK. Running this exact same script, but removing the `return`, outputs to me exactly what you want, the url with ".ics" in the url.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar is there a reason why removing the return would cause the element invisible to not be generated? The reason why I have return is that I want to pass the URL into another function

Comment: Probably not, it prints `URL:  https://registrar.fas.harvard.edu/calendar/upcoming/all/export.ics` to me, but coldspeed's answer is very suitable! =)

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar Thanks anyways for your comments, I appreciate a second pair of eyes anytime!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend streamlining your search by passing a css `href` selector and regex pattern:

```
links = soup.find_all('a', {'href' : re.compile('.*\.ics') })
```

Output:

```
[<a class="subscribe" href="https://registrar.fas.harvard.edu/calendar/upcoming/all/export.ics">subscribe</a>,
 <a class="ical" href="https://registrar.fas.harvard.edu/calendar/upcoming/all/export.ics">iCal</a>]
```

You won't have to jump through hoops to validate your anchor tags now.

Comment: @COLDSPEED awesome, thank you so much! Will accept once time allows me to

Comment: @MQ1217 Glad to help. :)